# ¿Cómo definir un regex para nombres compuestos?

Tags: regex

Actualmente me encuentro realizando una aplicación en angular 11. Necesito validar el formato correcto del campo input de nombre de usuario, utilizando el `Validators.pattern()` de reactive form.

Nombres correctos:

- Luis Enrique
- Ma. Enriqueta
- Ivan Van-Persi
- Donovan, Arturo

Nombres incorrectos:

- Ma.. Enriqueta
- Luis/ Enrique
- J. .. ..

Los únicos caracteres permitidos para separar los nombres compuestos son `.`, `-`, `,`,  ;
de igual manera debe validar que los nombres terminen con un carácter valido de A-Z.

```
/^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿñÑ]+(([,\. -][a-zA-ZÀ-ÿñÑ ])?[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿñÑ]*)*[^\w\s\d\(\)\[\]\?]$/
```

Actualmente esa es la estructura de regex que creé, sin embargo no funciona, ya que permite finalizar con caracteres especiales no permitidos.

Aceptar tildes (acentos) y Ñ está permitido.

Answer (score 1):

Disto mucho de ser experto en Expresiones regulares, pero tal vez esto te ayude:

```js
/^([a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ]{2,60}[\,\-\.]{0,1}[\s]{0,1}){1,3}$/
```

Si probamos con los test que has puesto de ejemplo, y algunos más de mi invención:

```js
const pattern = /^([a-zA-ZáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜñÑ]{2,60}[\,\-\.]{0,1}[\s]{0,1}){1,3}$/;

const testCases = [
  'Luis Enrique',     // true
  'Ma. Enriqueta',    // true
  'Ivan Van-Persi',   // true
  'Donovan, Arturo',  // true
  'Ma.. Enriqueta',   // false
  'Luis/ Enrique',    // false
  'J. .. ..',         // false
  'Juan José María',  // true
  'c ',               // false
  'D. Alfonso',       // false
  'Ma .Alejandra'     // false
];

testCases.forEach(w => {
  console.log(pattern.test(w));
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como puedes apreciar, no es muy complicada, acepta hasta un máximo de 3 palabras, y ninguna palabra puede tener menos de 2 letras o más de 60.

He escrito explícitmanente los caracteres del alfabeto latino para acentos y diéresis.

Acepta máximo 1 carácter de los separadores `,` `.` y `-` y se combinan para ser seguidos (o no) por un espacio. Al contrario no lo acepta.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.